# New install: black screen and no keyboard after boot sequence

Tags: boot, boot-issues

I've dusted off my old Raspberry Pi, flashed Raspberry Pi OS Lite to a new SD card, and tried to get it going again.

It boots, runs through the startup sequence, and then goes to a black screen. Unlike other "black screen" questions I found when I tried looking this up, I also don't have a command prompt!

I took a video of it, here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z7TlvVjUZvk

I tested the USB keyboard on another system and it seems to work fine. I note that while plugged in to the RasPi pressing numlock will light/dim the num lock LED, and so will scroll lock, but caps lock will not (in case that indicates anything).

Looking at my router's config page, I see that it has been allocated an IP address, though I get "connection refused" if I try to SSH into it.

Any ideas?

Comment: What Pi? How did you "flashed Raspberry Pi OS Lite to a new SD card"?  What screen? What does "runs through the startup sequence" mean?

Comment: Respectively: a first or second generation one (I can't remember), I can't remember, and I'm not sure I can describe the screen or startup sequence any more clearly, that's why I took the video. You know, the one with lots of lines like "[ OK ] ...... blah blah blah" on it?